# How does jq work with keys containing slash?

Tags: jq

My test json file is as follows:

```
{
   "server":"xxx",
   "cert":"line1\nline2",
   "security/path": "/var/log/systems.log"
}
```

I would like to filter by key `security/path`, and below commands all don't work.

```
jq .security/path test.json
jq: error: path/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.security/path
jq: 1 compile error
```

`jq '.security/path' test.json` has same result.

Answer (score 22):

From [Basic filters](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters):

> **Object Identifier-Index**:
>
> ...
>
> If the key contains special characters or starts with a digit, you
> need to surround it with double quotes like this: `."foo$"`, or else
> `.["foo$"]`
>
> ....

So,

```
$ jq -r '."security/path"' test.json
/var/log/systems.log
```

Answer (score 1):

In case your output is something like this,

```
  "annotations": {
    "eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn": "arn:aws:iam::907636088649:role/stg-eks_helm-chart",
    "meta.helm.sh/release-name": "helm-chart-base",
    "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": "stg-helm-chart"
  }
```

Following will work,

```
jq -r '.metadata.annotations["eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn"]'
```

and will produce an output like this,

```
arn:aws:iam::907636088649:role/stg-eks_helm-chart
```

Comment: You would not use `tr` to remove the double quotes, you would use `jq` with its `-r` option. That way you get the properly decoded string from `jq` (which would make a difference, for example, to the `cert` string in the question, which contains an encoded newline).  Note too that your answer seems to be identical to the older answer from steeldriver, and that you're using broken JSON which `jq` will not parse as an example.

Comment: kinda identical yes, just posted what I was trying to do, -r yea missed that, and updated the answer. Thanks.